# SQLITE Many-to-many relationship IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have 2 tables from sqlite;

**Jobs Table**

```
-id : PK
-name
-desc
-salary range
-tags
-courseId(s) : FK
```

**Course Table**

```
-courseId : PK
-name
-desc
-school
-program
```

The courseId from the Jobs Table has multiple numbers... Let's say if your job is a system analyst.. Your course can be (1) computer science, (2) IT, (3) MIS  etc.. So basically, courseId (FK): 1, 2, 3 --- if I parse this NSString to NSNumbers, how can I get each of the corresponding attributes via courseId. I'm not yet coding so this is basically on my head. BTW, I'm using objective-c.

Comment: Well, i'm not much familiar with sqlite yet but if your use coredata then your all problem will solved regarding Relational database kind of stuff.

Comment: How do I do that in coredata? Unfortunately, I haven't looked into it yet since I thought that sqlite would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this doc for beginning of [coredata](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

And here is your answer [many-to-many](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB) relationship between two entity.

Some helpful links,

[How do you manage and use "Many to many" core data relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572657/how-do-you-manage-and-use-many-to-many-core-data-relationships)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

Coredata will save lot of time and many lines of code as well.