# Core data one to many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have a scenario where there is one entity that can have X number of items depending on what the user adds in.  I have another entity that needs a relationship to any number of the first entity.  That is quite easy, simply create a one-to-many relationship from the second entity to the first.

The problem I'm having is, what if the second entity can take a multiple number of each of the first entity?  I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Example:
Entity A contains: x, y, z
Entity B can contain (for example): 3 of x and 7 of y.  Or 8 of x, 7 of y, 2 of z.  All depending on what the user chooses in the app.

Comment: Are you asking how to model a many-to-many relationship using Core Data? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572657/how-do-you-manage-and-use-many-to-many-core-data-relationships

Comment: @followben Not quite.  I have it programmed as a many-to-many relationship.  But I need to add an extra constraint in having a count on the entities that are unique to the entity it has a many-to-many relationship with.

Comment: Core Data's many-to-many won't natively support that additional constraint, but it'd be easy enough to achieve via a join entity.

Comment: What do you mean by a join entity?  Is that like the answer I accepted?

Comment: Yeah, Dan's answer would do the trick. See also Apple's second worked example in the Many-to-many Relationships section of the Core Data Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10 i.e. "An advantage of the intermediate entity is that you can also use it to add more information to the relationship"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData will not let you model a (direct) relationship where you can add the same object to a to-many relationship more than once.

In your case you have 2 options that I can think of, both require you to model a new middleware relationship entity.

Suppose you have entity `A` and `B`. You now need to create an entity `AtoB` where `AtoB` structure is:

relationships:
a : to-one relationship to `A` entity
b : to-one relationship to `B` entity

1. the first option will let you manually keep the count of object `B` you like in property `bCount`:

   1. each time a user link `A` to `B` you will increase the count of the existing relationship or create a new `AtoB` object with the proper values (beware duplicates)
2. the second option is to let the user add as many `AtoB` relationships (no uniqueness) when he link `A` entity to `B` entity:

   1. when needed get the count for these items manually or by grouping

I would prefer the first option in most cases.

The `A` entity and `B` entity will have a to-many relationship to the `AtoB` entity.

You can keep the to-many relationship from `B` to `A` you already have as I'm sure it has its purpose.

Comment: I like this approach!  A little cumbersome, but makes sense.  To bad there wasn't an easier way

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example of Many-To-Many]

In this example there is a User entity that can have multiple lists, but the lists can also have multiple users. Then the list also has tasks, but these tasks can also be apart of multiple lists.

For example

**Users:**
 1. Jeff
 2. Rose

**Lists:**
 1. Shopping 
 2. Homework
 3. Chores

**Tasks:**
1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

**Exmaple**

```
Rose -> Shopping   -> Task 1, Task 3, Task 4
     -> Chores     -> Task 2, Task 4

Jeff -> Homework   -> Task 3, Task 5
     -> Chores     -> Task 2, Task 4
```

**EDIT**

This is how you would go about displaying the different information about the users and their data.

```
// Fetch user 
User *user = [self getUserWithName:@"Rose"];

// Loop through lists
for (List *listObject in [user lists])
{
    // PRINT: (List Name) : (# of Tasks)
    NSLog(@"%@ : %lu", [listObject listName], (unsigned int)[[listObject tasks] count]);
}
```

For example this would print the following output because of the data that we gave rose for the example.

```
Shopping : 4 
Chores   : 2
```

**EDIT 2:**

IF you create an **userId** field under the entitys **User** and **Task** and create a userId for each individual user then you can filter out the Tasks based on the user using the same model as above with just a simple NSPredicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId == %@", @"123456789"];
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  In you example, I would need something that can do:  "Rose has 3 Shoppings and 2 Homeworks".  Jeff has "1 Shopping and 5 Chores"

Comment: Well once you get a reference to an User entity, for example Rose you can just count the number of objects in them take this for example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If I give Rose a Shopping and a Chore, she has two objects.  I want to specify the number of Shopping and Chores she has. Lets use a different example.  Instead of shopping, let's say it's pickles. And Chores is hotdogs.  How would I give Rose 6 pickles and 3 hotdogs.  And then Jeff 9 pickles and 2 hot dots

Comment: Actually wait.  In your example, I think Shopping will always have a count of 4 tasks.  I'd like it to be different for each User

Comment: You could add a property to task of **userId** and the do a NSPredicate on the Tasks to filter it for only the tasks specific to the user.

Comment: Is that the best option though?  Wouldn't it be easier to put a quantity property on the Chore and have it someway be unique across users

Comment: You could also do it with a type of triangle relationship where they are essentially all many-to-many relationships with each other. You still are going to have to do some sort of filtering based off ot that. If you do it that way you will have to have each Tas point at a user and a list. Then when trying to access each level, like to see what lists a user has, you are going to have to check wether it has a relationship to the same user as its Tasks do.