# Creating a many to many relationship with NSSet in ios 7

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, many-to-many, nsset

I have the following SqlLite tables:

```
Users
Attribute
email (is unique)
Relationships
friendsOfUser

Friends
Attribute
active (yes or no)
email (is unique with combination of freindsToUser)
Relationship
friendsToUser
```

I can create the User and Friend table but how do I create the NSSets for friendsOfUser and friendsToUser? I create the User entity first with an email and then create a friend by setting active and email. Initially the many to many relationship is blank. How do I update this in core data.

Comment: How about a UsersFriends join table?

Comment: correct but how do you use it correctly in core data?

Comment: do you need to implement these: CoreDataGeneratedAccessors) or do they come prebuilt into the custom class

Comment: like how do I use/implement this: - (void)addFriendsToUsers:(NSSet *)values;

Comment: Here's a good-seeming answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572657/how-do-you-manage-and-use-many-to-many-core-data-relationships