# Core Data Cross Reference Table (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, core-data

Imagine I have an app with two Core Data entities: ingredients and cookies.

Ingredients have a title, a type, an image, and a few other properties.
Cookies have a title, a type, an image and a few other properties.

A cookie is comprised of several ingredients. Ingredients can be used in multiple different cookies. The Cookie entity and the Ingredient entity have an inverse relationship which allows me to see which cookies have which ingredients and which ingredients are used in which cookies.

All of this is working fine.

Here is my problem:
In addition to several other ingredients of varying quantities, chocolate chip cookies require one egg but oatmeal raisin cookies require two eggs.

If I was designing a MySQL database to model all this, I'd have a Cookie table (similar to my Cookie Core Data entity), an Ingredient table (similar to my Ingredient Core Data entity), and a cross-reference table CookieIngredient, which would include a cookieID, an ingredientID, and a quantity.

I've tried to do this in Core Data, but I can't seem to get the entity for the cross-reference table created correctly. I create an Entity named CookieIngredient with Integer 16 fields of cookieID, ingredientID, and quantity, but then when I attempt to create an NSManagedObject Subclass, the class which is created -- unlike the other two classes -- displays numerous errors telling me "extensions cannot contain stored properties", which doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything else in the universe.

None of the many "recipe" Swift tutorials I've found online use Core Data, and the ones that do don't use a cross-reference table.

Any suggestions appreciated. (Am I doing this the wrong way?)

```
do{
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Ingredient> = Ingredient.createFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", title)
    let fetchedResults = try the_context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if let anIngredient = fetchedResults.first {
        let the_recipe = CookieIngredient(context: the_context)
        the_recipe.quantity = amount
        the_recipe.unit = unit
        the_recipe.mutableSetValue(forKey: "recipeIngredient").add(anIngredient)
        the_recipe.mutableSetValue(forKey: "recipeCookie").add(Cookie)
    }
}
catch{
    print( "unable to update ingredients" )
}
```

Assuming I have a Cookie object, I should be able to do this. But the error I'm getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSManagedObjects of entity 'CookieIngredient' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'recipeIngredient''
```

Is mutableSetValue not the correct way to create the relationship?

Note: mutableSetValue was *not* the correct way to do it.

```
extension CookieIngredient {

    @nonobjc public class func createfetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CookieIngredient> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CookieIngredient>(entityName: "CookieIngredient")
    }

    @NSManaged public var quantity: String
    @NSManaged public var unit: String
    @NSManaged public var recipeCookie: Cookie
    @NSManaged public var recipeIngredient: Ingredient
}
```

Comment: Could you include the generated source for the CookieIngredient class?

Comment: Always post your code. Telling people about your problem without any reference is hard to debug :)

Comment: You are on the right track creating the intermediate CookieIngredient entity, but the CoreData way is to have to-one relationships from CookieIngredient to Cookie and to Ingredient (both with to-many inverses) instead of the cookieID and ingredientID attributes (and also instead of the many-many relationship from Cookie to Ingredient).  This is described in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) in the section curiously entitled “Modelling a Relationship based on its semantics”.

Comment: @PeejWeej -- There was really no code to include, since I was working with the xcdatamodeld GUI, and the CookieIngredient class looks exactly the same as the Cookie class.
But I see your point, of course.
That being said: It turns out that there was nothing wrong with what I was doing. The problem was almost certainly because of the way XCode fails to properly save changes to the data model. There was a CookieIngredient+CoreDataProperties.swift file that existed but wasn't being displayed in the file navigator, for example, until I quit and restarted XCode.

Comment: ah...the good 'ol "have you tried turning it off and on again" trick! unfortunately necessary quite often with Xcode... For future reference, screenshots of your data model are a good option in this case.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for the reply. I've read that article a dozen times over the last week and still can't seem to understand. If my CookieIngredient table has only one attribute of quantity, then when I am adding a new "row" to that table, how do I associate the ingredient with the cookie?
I get that it will know which cookie (or which ingredient) when I'm adding the "row" to that "table" because I have to instantiate it *from* the other entity, but I still feel like there's a piece missing.

Comment: Suppose you create a Cookie: `let myCookie = Cookie(context: moc)` and you create an Ingredient: `let myIngredient = Ingredient(context: moc)`, then to relate the two you might use: `let myCI = CookieIngredient(context: moc); myCI.cookie = myCookie; myCI.ingredient = myIngredient; myCI.amount = 8.0`.  More likely the Ingredients already exist and are fetched, displayed in a tableView, and the user selects from there - but the principle is the same, you do have to specifically create the CookieIngredient object and assign a Cookie and an Ingredient to it.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Yes, @pbasdf, that does make sense.
I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293816/1357009) which shows a similar data model but (as usual) doesn't explain how to *add* to the cross reference table. I think I got it now and will try using your example.

PS: My actual app has nothing to do with cookies or recipes, but my son has been watching Cookie Monster for weeks and it's a much simpler way to explain.

Comment: Also: You know what would be fantastic? I would _love_ it if XCode didn't **crash** with no information whatever every time I make a change to the data model.

Comment: @pbasdf I've added some code to my original question. I can't seem to get the relationship to add using mutableSetValue, although that's how I've done it for another entity and it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: If the recipeIngredient relationship is to-one (it should be - each CookieIngredient is related one Cookie and one Ingredient), there is no need to use mutableSetValueForKey.  In that respect life just got easier: `the_recipe.recipeIngredient = anIngredient`

Comment: @pbasdf Hm. Each recipeIngredient _is_ related to one cookie, but a cookie can have many ingredients. So the Relationship on the recipeIngredient table is to-one but the inverse Relationship of it on the Cookie table is to-many. Right?

I think I've got it working now, but (of course) I have to add constraints so that chocolate chip cookie cannot have multiple "one egg" ingredients. Can relationship constraints be added the same way attribute constraints can?

Comment: @pbasdf FYI I was not able to simply use the_recipe.recipeIngredient = anIngredient, but instead had to use the_recipe.setValue(anIngredient, forKeyPath: "recipeIngredient")

Comment: Yes, the inverse relationship is to-many: each Cookie can have many CookieIngredients.  Adding constraints will have to be managed in code, as far as I know there is no easy way to do this in the model.  If Xcode is not recognising the properties for CookieIngredients, that suggests your model is not generating the subclass code - which might be related to your original problem.  Check the codegen option in the model editor.

Comment: @pbasdf I am manually generating the class. I added it to the original question. I think the problem was that I had the relationships set as NSSet but I am going to try (see above) making them the Entities themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160744/discussion-between-david-vincent-gagne-and-pbasdf).