# Core Data move or link entity between relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In `Core Data` I have a `House` Entity which has a relationship to a `Room` entity. The `Room` entity itself has a `many-to-many` relationship with a `Door` entity.

[image]

Two rooms might share the same door, so here is what I need to know:

- Is it possible to have two `Room` entities with a relationship to the same **`Door`** entity. And when updating the properties of the `Door` entity, it will be the same object and gets updated in both `Room` entities.
- Is it possible to move the `Door` entity from one relationship to another, without copying it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-many relationship between `Room` and `Door`. This means that those relationships behave as a `Set`, so you can call `myDoor.doors.remove(room)`, or `.insert()` to manage the entity. These are reciprocal as well, like all Core Data relationships (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572657/how-do-you-manage-and-use-many-to-many-core-data-relationships) for further details). Do note your naming scheme is a bit confusing, and for example I'd recommend switching to using `myDoor.rooms`